# Creating ledger account with help of PHP, MySQL, and HTML table

Tags: php, html, mysql, html-table

All works fine for me as the title says, but the problem is with **HTML Table**.

What I am getting:

[image]

What I want:

[image]

The Code I am executing:

```
<?php
    $id = $rowpt['Id'];
    $lstmt = $user_home->runQuery("SELECT * FROM received WHERE Id = :fn");
    $lstmt->bindParam(':fn',$id);
    $lstmt->execute();
    // Left Hand Side Columns
        while($lrow=$lstmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
        {
            extract($lrow);

?>    
    <tr>
    <td><?php echo $Date; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $Reason; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $Amnt; ?></td>
    <td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td>
    </tr>
    <?php
    }
    $lstmtc = $user_home->runQuery("SELECT * FROM payment WHERE Id = :fn ORDER BY Sr ASC");
    $lstmtc->bindParam(':fn',$id);
    $lstmtc->execute();
    // Right Hand Side Columns
        while($lrowc=$lstmtc->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
        {
            extract($lrowc);

?>    
    <tr>
    <td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td>
    <td><?php echo $Date; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $Reason; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $Amnt; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
```

What changes should I make in the code, so that I get my expected results?

**UPDATE**

After executing codes provided at [answer by JokerDan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48972364/8617951) worked fine. After increasing some more rows I got the result as:

[image]

> The right column is repeated

Comment: Unclosed `tr` tag, `<tr>` => `</tr>`

Comment: Thank you for alerting me, the tags are now closed

Comment: Nothing changed in result after that?

Comment: No, no changes after that...

Comment: There are many ways to do this. For instance: First get both the 'received' and 'payment' data and store them in an array. Then create the table and pick data from the arrays until neither one has any data left. Be adventurous: use a function!

Comment: @KIKOSoftware your comment seems will work perfect for me, I will be thankful if you help me with the example codes.... Hope you understand

Comment: You seem to understand what I said, then why can't you do it yourself?

Comment: I don't know the perfect code, so please help me out...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is with your table structure.

Your first query outputs a table as so;

```
<tr>
    <td><?php echo $Date; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $Reason; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $Amnt; ?></td>
    <td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td>
</tr>
```

This is 3 populated cells followed by 4 unpopulated cells on one row, then you close the row for the table and go to the next part on the second SQL transaction.

```
<tr>
    <td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td>
    <td><?php echo $Date; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $Reason; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $Amnt; ?></td>
</tr>
```

This is on a new row, you are putting 4 unpopulated cells followed by 3 populated ones. Thus your transaction table is a bit off.

As to how to solve it, it might be best to look at doing your query as a join in order to get both received and payment table data and then construct the table.

Here is an article/guide on doing joins for tables.
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-using-joins.htm

---

Without proper knowledge of your setup, this is the best solution as close to your current implementation;

```
<?php
$id = $rowpt['Id'];
$lstmt = $user_home->runQuery("SELECT * FROM received WHERE Id = :fn");
$lstmt->bindParam(':fn',$id);
$lstmt->execute();

while($left = $lstmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
  extract($left);
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" . $left["date"] . "</td>" . "<td>" . $left["reason"] . "</td>" . "<td>" . $left["amnt"] . "</td>" . "<td></td>";
  $tRow = 1;
  $lstmtc = $user_home->runQuery("SELECT * FROM payment WHERE Id = :fn ORDER BY Sr ASC");
  $lstmtc->bindParam(':fn',$id);
  $lstmtc->execute();
  while($right = $lstmtc->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    extract($right);
    if ($right["id"] == $left["id"]) {
      if ($tRow != 1) { echo "<tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td>"; }
      echo "<td>" . $right["date"] . "</td>" . "<td>" . $right["reason"] . "</td>" . "<td>" . $right["amnt"] . "</td>";
      if ($tRow != 1) { echo "</tr>"; }
      $tRow++;
    }
  }
  echo "</tr>";
}
?>
```

---

Update, after realizing exactly what you needed, I threw some tables together and put this together, I am using mariaDB and the joins I thought would work were not for some reason, so here we make two different calls, build both sides of the table and then output them together.

```
<?php
// My test DB connection
$db = new PDO("mysql:dbname=test;host=localhost", "test", "test");
// ID we are looking for
$id = 1;

$received = "SELECT * FROM received WHERE id = :fn";
$payments = "SELECT * FROM payments WHERE id = :fn";

$dbQuery = $db->prepare($payments);
$dbQuery->bindParam(':fn', $id);
$dbQuery->execute();

$leftRows = [];

while ( $left = $dbQuery->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) ) {
  $leftRows[] = ("<td>" . $left["date"] . "</td>" . "<td>" . $left["reason"] . "</td>" . "<td>" . $left["amnt"] . "</td>" . "<td></td>");
}

$rightRows = [];

$dbQuery = $db->prepare($received);
$dbQuery->bindParam(':fn', $id);
$dbQuery->execute();

while ( $right = $dbQuery->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) ) {
  $rightRows[] = ("<td>" . $right["date"] . "</td>" . "<td>" . $right["reason"] . "</td>" . "<td>" . $right["amnt"] . "</td>");
}

echo "<table>";
for ($i = 0; $i < count($leftRows) || $i < count($rightRows); $i++) {
  echo "<tr>";
  if (empty($leftRows[$i])) echo "<td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td>"; else echo $leftRows[$i];
  if (empty($rightRows[$i])) echo "<td></td><td></td><td></td>"; else echo $rightRows[$i];
  echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
?>
```

Comment: I had edited the question with some updates related to your answer, thank you for helping.

Comment: @Namo so the right column is repeating when it shouldn't be? What are the ID's for those rows in your payment table?

Comment: The meaning of  `Id` in my code is that, the Id of the customer. So, the `Id` for both payment & received table are same

Comment: Oh, so the left side is not tied to the right side of the table? You simply want to output essentially two tables side by side but in one html table?

Comment: Yes, you understood

Comment: @Namo See my updated answer, bottom section of PHP code. You may need to adjust it slightly but I am getting a table output as you seem to want?